# How do I get a python program to do nothing?

Tags: python

How do I get a `Python` program to do nothing with if statement?

```
 if (num2 == num5):
     #No changes are made
```

Comment: @Polli Ester If one of the answers below helped you, it would be good to accept it (click the tick underneath the score for it).

Answer (score 142):

You could use a `pass` statement:

```
if condition:
    pass
```

[Python 2.x documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement)

[Python 3.x documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement)

However I doubt you want to do this, unless you just need to put something in as a placeholder until you come back and write the actual code for the `if` statement.

If you have something like this:

```
if condition:        # condition in your case being `num2 == num5`
    pass
else:
    do_something()
```

You can in general change it to this:

```
if not condition:
    do_something()
```

But in this specific case you could (and should) do this:

```
if num2 != num5:        # != is the not-equal-to operator
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 22):

The `pass` command is what you are looking for. Use `pass` for any construct that you want to "ignore". Your example uses a conditional expression but you can do the same for almost anything.

For your specific use case, perhaps you'd want to test the opposite condition and only perform an action if the condition is false:

```
if num2 != num5:
    make_some_changes()
```

This will be the same as this:

```
if num2 == num5:
    pass
else:
    make_some_changes()
```

That way you won't even have to use `pass` and you'll also be closer to adhering to the ["Flatter is better than nested" convention in PEP20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

---

You can read more about the `pass` statement [in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements):

> The pass statement does nothing. It can be used when a statement is required syntactically but the program requires no action.

```
if condition:
    pass
```

```
try:
    make_some_changes()
except Exception:
    pass # do nothing
```

```
class Foo():
    pass # an empty class definition
```

```
def bar():
    pass # an empty function definition
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use pass inside if statement.

Comment: I think you could have put a little bit more effort into this "answer". It looks more like a comment...

Answer (score -4):

```
if (num2 == num5):
    for i in []: #do nothing
        do = None
else:
    do = True
```

or my personal favorite

```
if (num2 == num5):
    while False: #do nothing
        do = None
else:
    do = True
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of why you believe this answer is more useful than the accepted one.

Comment: This is a terrible solution. It actually is doing something by setting the do variable.

Answer (score -8):

You can use continue

```
if condition:
    continue
else:
    #do something
```

Comment: In case you don't understand why you got voted down, the reason is because your answer is *wrong*. The `continue` statement is used to change the execution of a loop, not to break out of an `if` statement. If you had tried the solution you offered, you would have discovered that Python complains about incorrect syntax.